# React to changes of a view model property in the code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

What is the best way to react on a change of a property named *foo* of the view model (of unspecified type) in the code behind, assuming the view model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly?

Usually one can bind control elements to view model properties and everything works. But in this case, this is not enough and I need to execute some lines of c# when the property changes.

One could listen to the corresponding event of the DataContext, but then, I have also handle changes of the DataContext itself. Another possible solution would be to introduce a `DependencyProperty` in the code behind file. But isn't there a shorter way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but why not react to the changes of the bound property directly in the ViewModel?

Comment: Good question, should have mention this in the question. The reason is that the I need to modify the controls directly (by adding columns to a specific control). I do not want to do that in the view model.

Comment: So what is bound to property Foo?

Comment: I would like to bind the `ItemsSource` element of the control mentioned above to `foo`. However, in that case `foo` is expected to be a list of objects of some fixed type. If that was the case, for each public property of this type, a column would be generated automatically. But, in my case the number of columns is not known in advance, so I have to generate them manually. Hence, instead of binding `foo` to `ItemsSource`, I would like to bind it to something defined in the code behind, which triggers a function call, when the value of `foo` has changed.

Comment: If foo was ObservableCollection of objects, then you can subscribe to collection changed event in your code behind, it will fire any time you add or remove from the collection. I guess there is nothing stopping you from creating observable collection out of your list?

Comment: How about deriving from that control and register another PropertyChanged callback for the ItemsSource property.

Comment: @adminSoftDK: Making the list an ObservableCollection tells me when the contents of the list changes, but not when the list object is replaced or set.

Comment: I just checked it, and it will tell you, when Add, Move, Remove, Replace, Reset. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I posted a possible solution, I need to go now, but have a look at it.

Comment: @MarkusParker I’m facing a similar issue. Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: @Ash After more than one additional year of WPF experience I would go with a dedicated DependencyProperty defined in the code behind. It is a few lines of boilerplate code to write, but it is the cleanest solution I can think of. Bind the dependency property to the property in the view model and define a callback in the PropertyMetadata constructor when calling `DependencyProperty.Register()`.

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend avoiding this when possible. If it is necessary, subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event.

I would put this code in the code behinds constructor.

```
INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel = (INotifyPropertyChanged)this.DataContext; 
viewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => {
    if (!args.PropertyName.Equals("foo"))
        return;
    // execute code here.
};
```

**Maintainability tip** If you know for sure that the data context is a type that has the property, cast to that type and use the `nameof` operator rather than a magic string.

**Edit (reacting to datacontext changes)**

You should be able to subscribe to the DataContextChanged event to handle changes in the data context.

```
INotifyPropertyChanged previous;
// constructor
public SomeCodeBehindClass()
{
    previous = (INotifyPropertyChanged)this.DataContext;
    DataContextChanged += (sender, args) => SubscribeToFooChanges((INotifyPropertyChanged)args.NewValue);
    SubscribeToFooChanges(previous);
}

// subscriber
private void SubscribeToFooChanges(INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel)
{
    if (previous != null)
        previous.PropertyChanged -= FooChanged;
    previous = viewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
        viewModel.PropertyChanged += FooChanged;
}

// event handler
private void FooChanged (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.PropertyName.Equals("foo"))
        return;
    // execute code here.
}
```

Comment: This is a valid solution, but as I stated above, one has to do extra work  when `this.DataContext` changes. When using bindings in xaml this is not necessary. I wonder if it is possible to do something similar in code behind.

Comment: I've added an example of using the DataContextChanged DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler. I haven't ran the code.

Comment: You need to do a null check on `previous` and on `viewModel` in your SubscribeToFooChanges method, since the DataContext starts off null and the can be assigned to null as well.

Comment: I am trying to get more information on why some consider this a bad pattern. It seems necessary in scenarios where you need complex View logic to be performed when a ViewModel property is changed.

Comment: @Chucky I'd say view logic is fine to put in the code-behind as long as its put in something like a custom control and bound to the view-model with an actual xaml binding. That makes it easy to separate what is truly "view logic" from "business logic." It also means you can always look at the xaml of a view to see all the bindings, without extra "hidden" bindings in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution, in you code behind you could do this

```
 (((dynamic)DataContext).foo as ObservableCollection<object>).CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
            {

            }
            else
            {
               //and so on
            }
        };
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach, however, it does not consider if either the DataContext changes or the variable `foo` is assigned another value.

Comment: @MarkusParker DataContextChanged is an event which you can access easly in the code behind. And assigning the entire collection to a new value is not a good idea, as all your bindings needs to be re-assigned then (here is some reading about it http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection). Its better to clear the collection.

Answer (score -1):

If these lines of code related to business logic, you should not use them in the code behind.
In other cases, the properties of the view model will always be bound to any markup element, if this property value must somehow be preprocessed you should use Converters